# Passing String to Prepared Statement in Golang

Tags: string, postgresql, go, prepared-statement

The idea is I want to update the `status` and returning the id only if the `status` is different.

So, I have a prepared statement like this:

```
var theQuery = `UPDATE process SET status=$1 WHERE status!=$1 AND id=$2 RETURNING id`
```

Then, I called it with this:

```
err = statement.QueryRow("set", 12).Scan(&id)
```

Then there is an error appear like this.

```
runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
```

When I tried:

```
var theQuery = `UPDATE process SET status='$1' WHERE status!='$1' AND id=$2 RETURNING id`
```

It runs. Then, when I run it again, I am expecting to get `no rows`, but it still returning the id. It looked like it still updating the rows and ignored the `status!='$1'` part.

Thank you

Comment: `QueryRow()` usually takes a query string, followed by n parameters. Not sure what `"set"` is doing. Did you mean to pass `theQuery`? Something like `QueryRow(theQuery,arg1,arg2)`

Comment: @anthony That is `Stmt.QueryRow()`, which takes just the args. The statement is already prepared. https://godoc.org/database/sql#Stmt.QueryRow

Comment: You are getting an error because you have two params ($1 and $2) in that statement, but you are only passing one ("set"). Why?

Comment: @RayfenWindspear Sorry, my mistakes. I write it wrong. Okay, I have edit the question. Actually I just find the solution. I'll answer it then.

Answer (score 1):

So, I just find the solution. Instead of using `$1` twice, the prepared statement will received 3 arguments:

```
var theQuery = `UPDATE process SET status=$1 WHERE status!=$2 AND id=$3 RETURNING id`
```

Then, I call the prepared statement like this.

```
status := "set"
err = statement.QueryRow(status, status, 12).Scan(&id)
```

I know maybe this is not the best approach to solve the problem. But it worked for me.

Comment: That's actually very interesting that this fixes it. I wonder what the underlying cause is. Also, if you are using just the bare `database/sql` package, might I suggest `github.com/jmoiron/sqlx`. It comes with some extra features which are nice to have. Unless you'd rather not use a third party library.

Comment: I also curious how using `$1` twice didn't work. I'll keep the question open hoping others may know it. Yeah, I'm using `database/sql` for now, I'm keeping `github.com/jmoiron/sqlx` for next project though.